# generating graphs using chartkick in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts

I am using chartkick to generate graphs in my Rails 4 application. I need to map the clickcount of each of my affiliates into a graph for the maintainer of the affiliate sites.
So I have used the following

```
<%= column_chart [name:@affiliate_person.affiliates.map{|t| [t.name]} , data: @affiliate_person.affiliates.map{|t| [t.click_count] }] %>
```

Each affiliate_person will have many affiliates and I want to show for each affiliate site how much clicks have been generated. How do I do this? The readme is not very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is a column chart just needs a 1-1 association for a label of the data and the amount to represent. Try this:

```
column_chart @affiliate_person.affiliates.map { |t| [t.name, t.click_count] }
```